# How to Diagnose Phoenix Framework "Server Internal Error"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting an error on my newly deployed Phoenix application (on Heroku).

The only error I see in production in "Server internal error".

How do I get more information and diagnose/fix this error?

Comment: You should have something in your logs. Try `heroku logs -f` and perform a web request. One common reason is not running the migrations.

Comment: ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function DateTime.utc_now/0 (module DateTime is not available) ...I'm using `<%= DateTime.utc_now.year %>` in my footer. Works in dev though.

Comment: For future reference, it would have probably saved you some time if you'd identified the versions of all of the software in question right from the start.   @Gazler knew exactly the issue once he figured out what your version of Elixir is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use an Elixir 1.3 feature (`DateTime` was added in 1.3), however by default, the heroku buildpack uses Elixir 1.2

Add an `elixir_buildpack.config` file in the root of your repo with the following:

```
elixir_version=1.3.2
```